# Leetcode: divide without multiplication, division, and mod operator

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I am new to this and would like to know some basic tips to make my coding more efficient, because on this question my code is obviously not efficient enough for the practice problem and I looked in the discussion and couldn't really find anything to help with this wall. (I am not a plagiarist)

The problem is from [LeetCode Exercise 29. Divide 2 Integers](https://leetcode.com/problems/divide-two-integers/description/):

> Divide two integers without using multiplication, division and mod operator.
>
> If it is overflow, return MAX_INT.

Here is the code

```
   //I know I am going to use only standard libraries and don't plan on any //name collisions
    using namespace std;

    class Solution {
    public:
        long long int divide(long long int dividend, long long int divisor) {
    //boolean that is used for negative numbers
        bool converted = false;
    //asnwer
        long long int count = 0;
    //if it brings up 0 then it would simply return 0
        if (divisor == 0) {
            cout<<count<<endl;
            return count;
        }
    //it's an attempt to handle over flow ,but the huge numbers are
    //still owning me
        if(divisor == 1)
            return dividend;
        if(dividend == INT_MIN && abs(divisor) == 1)
            return INT_MAX;

        while (dividend != 0) {
        //converting negitives to positive for simplicity of code
            if ((divisor < 0) && (dividend > 0)) {
                converted = true;
                divisor = -divisor;
            }
            else if ((divisor < 0) && (dividend < 0)){
                divisor = -divisor;
                dividend = -dividend;
            }
            else if ((divisor > 0) && (dividend < 0)){
                converted = true;
                dividend = -dividend;
            }
    //an attempt to try to get around this problem
            //if(dividend > 20000000000000000){
             //   dividend -= pow(divisor, 2);
             //   count += (pow(divisor, 2) - 1);
            //}
    //using subtraction to divide
            dividend -= divisor;
    //for calculation of remainders
            if (dividend < 0) {
                if (converted == true) {
                    cout<<-count<<" Remainder "<<dividend + divisor<<endl;
                    return -count;
                    break;
                }
                cout<<count<< " Remainder "<<dividend + divisor<<endl;
                return count;
                break;
            }
            count += 1;
        }
//converts negatives back to their negitive answer
        if (converted == true) {
            cout<<-count<<endl;
            return -count;
        }
        else{
//answer 
            cout<<count<<endl;
            return count;
        }
    }
        };
```

I would love any help with this, since I would need to learn how to apply this to get better at programming.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview.StackExchange. It is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. Would you be able to tell us more about it? Also, your code seems to be some sort of draft (code commented out, indentation issues, cout statements in the middle of the function), please make sure your code is as good as it can be before submitting it here so that you can have more interesting reviews :D

Comment: I wonder why you check for INT_MIN if the function has `long long int` parameters. Also the C++ template in the [original problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/divide-two-integers/description/) has `int` parameters.

Comment: Try to make the computer do like you'd do long division "using pencil&paper", just binary instead of whatever you'd use. Don't invest *too* much effort there - if a serious attempt to code that fails, read up on [binary restoring division](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Restoring_division) and its non-restoring variant.